# Show $ M $ is a characteristic subgroup of $ K $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ G $ is a soluble group. Let $ K/L $ be a chief factor of $ G $. Then $ K/L $ is a minimal normal subgroup of $ G/L $. Suppose $ M $ is the smallest normal subgroup of $ K $ that $ K/M $ is nilpotent. Hence $ M $ is the intersection of  normal subgroups $ T $ of $ K $ that $ K/T $ is nilpotent, so $ M \leq L $. Let $ \phi $ is a automorphism of $ K $. Why $ \phi(M) = M $ ?

Comment: I am sure you have this before! It is because $K/T$ is nilpotent if and only if $K/\phi(T)$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Your teacher says what is false?

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ is finite group, then there is no problem in proof:

> If $K/M_1$ is nilpotent, and $K/M_2$ is nilpotent then $K/(M_1\cap M_2)$ is also nilpotent.

Since $K/M_1$ is nilpotent, there exists $n\geq 2$ such that $\gamma_n(K/M_1)=1$ i.e. $\gamma_n(K)\subseteq M_1$. (Then, this subset-relation also holds for $n+1,n+2,\cdots$.)

Similarly there exists $m\geq 2$ such that $\gamma_m(K)\subseteq M_2$.

Taking maximum of $m,n$, say $n$, we have that 
$$\gamma_n(K)\subseteq M_1 \mbox{ and }\gamma_n(K)\subseteq M_2.$$
Thus, $\gamma_n(K)\subseteq M_1\cap M_2$ i.e. $\gamma_n(K/M_1\cap M_2)=1$, i.e. $K/M_1\cap M_2$ is nilpotent.

As you already mentioned, $M$ is **the smallest** normal subgroup of $K$ modulo which $K$ becomes nilpotent. So, $\phi(M)$ must be $M$.

---

I didn't see any role of $G$ and $L$. What is the exact problem?